# Attempting to validate XSL

Tags: xml, xslt

XSL newbie here. I am not sure if the XSL I have authored is valid. I am wanting for someone who has a better idea to tell me if it is or not.

Requirements:

- The "input" may contain an r-mark and that r-mark must display as a superscripted r-mark.
- The "input" may contain text wrapped in bold or italics tags, and that text must be bold or italicized.

Input:

```html
The Product&reg; is <b>important</b>!
```

Expected output: The Product® is **important**!

My solution:

```html
<xsl:choose>

<xsl:when test="(input != '')">

<xsl:variable name="var1"><xsl:value-of select="input"/></xsl:variable>

<xsl:value-of select="replace($var1, '&reg;', '<sup style='font-size:
0.6em; vertical align: 25%>&reg;</sup>')" disable-output-escaping="yes"/>

</xsl:when>

<xsl:otherwise></xsl:otherwise>

</xsl:choose>
```

Is this valid? Is there a more elegant solution I am not considering? Suggestions or feedback are welcome.

Comment: You should post a complete reproducible example. Include a sample input, the code you have written so far and the output you expect.

Comment: Any solution that relies on `disable-output-escaping` to produce markup is substandard. If you need to replace a character with an element, use the `xsl:analyze-string` instruction

Comment: Please post a [mcve], not snippets taken out of context.

Comment: @michael.hor257k, all I have to contrast is the existing XSL attribute: <xsl:value-of select="input"/> and when the data from the XML template field passed into that, the HTML markup and entity were visible.

Comment: I cannot help you without being able to reproduce the problem and knowing what the expected output (as code, not rendered) is.

Comment: Does the posted code work at all? The `select` attribute value of the `xsl:value-of` doesn't appear to be well-formed, with unescaped `<` characters.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the input is XML and has an entity reference `&reg;` for a defined entity `<!ENTITY reg "&#174;">`, in XSLT 2 or later I would push the contents of the `input` elements through templates that use the identity template (not shown below) to copy elements like `b` or `i` and for text nodes use `analyze-string` to check for the `®` sign and wrap it:

```
  <xsl:template match="input">
      <div>
          <xsl:apply-templates/>
      </div>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="input//text()">
      <xsl:analyze-string select="." regex="®">
          <xsl:matching-substring>
              <sup style="font-size:0.6em; vertical align: 25%;">
                  <xsl:value-of select="."/>
              </sup>
          </xsl:matching-substring>
          <xsl:non-matching-substring>
              <xsl:value-of select="."/>
          </xsl:non-matching-substring>
      </xsl:analyze-string>
  </xsl:template>
```